# insert item into wordpress the_posts() while loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a project in Wordpress and am outputting the posts on the homepage (layout is a bit complex, so there are a few if statements to determine which template-parts to use).

However i have a piece of functionality which is to display 1 specific post (toggled in the admin area) in a certain place - basically pinning the post to always display in the first array position.

I have two problems with the current way i've programmed this;

1 - the pinned article is replacing the post in that current position in the array, so the post in position one never gets displayed

2 - the pinned article may well appear in the_posts() so i don't want it displayed twice.

Whats the best way of dealing with these problems? I feel like there must be a better way

```
            $count = 0;
            $rows = 10;
            echo '<div class="grid-container grid-rows-' . $rows . '"">';
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                
                if($count === 0 || $count === 9 || $count === 10 || $count === 19){
                    echo '  <div class="grid-container-item '.$count.'">';
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                    echo '  </div>';
                }
                else{
                    if($count === 1) {
                        //display pinned_featurette content
                        if ( $wpb_pinned_content_query->have_posts() ) :
                            while ( $wpb_pinned_content_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_pinned_content_query->the_post();
                                    echo '<div class="grid-container-item pinned_ad">';
                                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min-ad', get_post_format() );
                                    echo '</div>';
                            endwhile;
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        //if none - place normal content
                        else :
                            
                            echo '<div class="grid-container-item '.$count.'">';
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min', get_post_format() );
                            echo '</div>';
                        endif;
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<div class="grid-container-item '.$count.'">';
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min', get_post_format() );
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }
                $count ++;
            endwhile;

            echo '</div>';
```

Comment: since it i another query on its own - you could just place it just before the while loop starts, ince it is always in number 1 spot. - that way you would not overwrite the first post in the loop. and since you are doing it before the loop now, you save the ID of the pinned post in a variable, and exclude that in upir while loop.

Comment: When I mean the first position, I mean in an array that starts at zero. (So it’s technically the second position)

Answer (score 0):

1. Exclude the pinned posts IDs from the homepage Query

   > ```
   >  add_action(
   >   'pre_get_posts',
   >   function( $query ) {
   >       if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
   >           $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 1, 2, 3, '# IDs of the pinned posts' ) );
   >       }
   >   },
   >   100,
   >   1
   > );
   > ```
2. to avoid replacing the post in the same position in the main loop

   ```
   $count = 0;
   $rows  = 10;
   echo '<div class="grid-container grid-rows-' . $rows . '"">';
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

       if( $count === 1 ) {
           //display pinned_featurette content
           if ( $wpb_pinned_content_query->have_posts() ) :
               while ( $wpb_pinned_content_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_pinned_content_query->the_post();
                       echo '<div class="grid-container-item pinned_ad">';
                               get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min-ad', get_post_format() );
                       echo '</div>';
               endwhile;
               wp_reset_postdata();
           endif;
       }

       if( $count === 0 || $count === 9 || $count === 10 || $count === 19 ) {
           echo '  <div class="grid-container-item '.$count.'">';
                       get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
           echo '  </div>';
       } else {
           echo '<div class="grid-container-item '.$count.'">';
               get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-min', get_post_format() );
           echo '</div>';
       }

       $count ++;
   endwhile;

   echo '</div>';
   ```

Comment: 2 works perfectly - so annoyed i didn't notice i was over-complicating the statements

Comment: 1 i can't get this to work - mainly cause i'm currently not trying to do this on the homepage, as this functionality also extends to the category archive pages - which i'm working on first. Tried removing the statement $query->is_home() but didn't see to make any difference

Comment: change it to "$query->is_category( array( 'category names' ) )"

Comment: FYI - there will only ever be one pinned post - have set the query to only return the latest pinned post. 

i've changed the code to this, but no luck;
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {
     if ( $query->is_category( 'category_slug' ) ) {
      $query->set( 'post__not_in', 13361 );
     }
    },
    100,
    1
   );

Comment: 13361 being the ID of the pinned post

Comment: It has to be array    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 13361 ) );

Comment: Still doesn't work, it's not making any difference, both pinned article and the original article are still showing in the list